# Parse a CSV into a pandas dataframe without dropping empty lines

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a tab separated file which looks like this:

```
time_point  COL1A1  COL1A2  ACTA2   MMP1    TGFb_indep
120.5   2.4368708456    2.7397795032    0.1363219507    0.0864637842    0
121 1.8424199632    2.5120095489    0.1298143655    0.0912919808    0
122 1.9638241905    2.6892349035    0.1067387391    0.0691376693    0
123 2.3264487357    3.0663649168    0.1487167855    0.0906078211    0
124 1.9111306243    3.1013070916    0.1334430791    0.0758170634    0
128 2.178030898 3.446027992 0.1279528707    0.0817450068    0
132 2.0877010754    3.2035358965    0.1212986296    0.0467952257    0
144 2.5405821891    3.2318699308    0.1660787202    0.0232173824    0
168 3.8196607541    4.4386301784    0.2278481418    0.0096855824    0
192 5.6809072904    5.4057371332    0.316546941 0.0030576762    0
216 6.2100964486    4.5358900665    0.2751968144    0.0109808662    0

120.5   1.8871528102    3.0664538707    0.1385118438    0.1116450543    0
121 1.7263163381    2.2211192542    0.1046306079    0.1017511394    0
122 1.3954984869    1.9406642741    0.0724319768    0.0869048534    0
123 1.7788798036    2.4797402932    0.1240582026    0.1087456075    0
124 1.7990099619    3.0991297898    0.1021409421    0.0874712776    0
128 1.3340691151    2.7177324043    0.121746602 0.0662573086    0
132 2.0310867907    3.2725197272    0.128716766 0.0439254808    0
144 1.6466766027    2.996082284 0.1392247152    0.0214132449    0
168 3.1344690032    3.4941972773    0.18797218  0.0036672925    0
192 5.6042994743    4.7215614619    0.2671004016    0.0057764708    0
216 6.5017267162    5.0517838682    0.2733029462    0.0055187717    0

120.5   1.3639060927    1.9018906704    0.0844806249    0.1057254287    0
121 1.4016527716    1.8399531066    0.0822288805    0.1211653422    0
122 1.572553287 2.2747671958    0.1189649844    0.1036497761    0
123 1.5284764041    1.7291994479    0.0966641189    0.0962255806    0
124 1.2868781898    2.0602872579    0.0929910385    0.0695230652    0
128 1.5388150552    2.3812182386    0.1074531625    0.0640201492    0
132 1.122722224 1.9258308992    0.083826548 0.0544045465    0
144 1.8468717406    2.5963838351    0.1276480744    0.0296577648    0
168 2.797855876 2.8019702692    0.2160177321    0.0097123198    0
192 4.395782804 3.8935876519    0.2666483128    0.0027911978    0
216 5.8888387226    4.5645833006    0.2298800484    0.0148278492    0
```

The white spaces are meaningful and need to be retained. How can I read this into a pandas dataframe?

```
pandas.read_csv('data_file.csv', sep'\t')
```

Automatically removes the lines with only spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the `skip_blank_lines=False` argument to `read_csv` -

```
pandas.read_csv('data_file.csv', sep'\t', skip_blank_lines=False)
```