# Gathering multiple text files containing multiple tables to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, read-csv

I'm trying to gather multiple csv files from one folder into a dataframe. With this [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76895183/12846804) we realized the real issue is that some csv files (*summary files*) contain more than one table. As a result, the current solution's product (code below) skips a significant portion of the data.

**Is there any reasonable way to gather multiple files, each possibly containing multiple tables?**

Alternatively, if this makes it easier, I have, and could use, separate text files for each of the tables contained in the larger summary files.

Anyhow, what I seek, is that a single **row** of the generated dataframe should contain the data from the three separate text files / three tables inside the summary file.

Here is my code for just adding the text files from their folder.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
import glob

#define path to dir containing the summary text files
files_folder = "/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/"

#create a df list using list comprehension
files = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', on_bad_lines='skip') for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_folder,"*txt"))] 

#concatanate the list of df's into one df
files_df = pd.concat(files)


print(files_df)
```

Here is an example file

| Sample Summary: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample ID: | 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sample Name: | 18RF0375 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Coverage Drop: | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Pipeline Version: | Var |  |  |  |  |  |
| Date: | 1/12/2023 9:55 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Target Coverage Summary: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Gene Name | Start | End | Flag |  |  |  |
| gyrB | 6571 | 6762 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| gyrA | 7360 | 7583 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| rpoB | 760307 | 761286 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| mmpR | 778989 | 779487 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| rplC1 | 800808 | 801462 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| atpE | 1461044 | 1461290 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| rrs | 1473245 | 1473331 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| rrl | 1473657 | 1476796 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| fabG1 | 1673409 | 1674052 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| inhA | 1674201 | 1675012 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| tlyA | 1917939 | 1918747 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| katG | 2153888 | 2156112 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| pncA | 2288676 | 2289272 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| eis | 2714123 | 2715372 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| ahpC | 2726093 | 2726194 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| pepQ | 2859299 | 2860418 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| embB | 4246586 | 4249653 | No deletion |  |  |  |
| ethA | 4326003 | 4327474 | No deletion |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Variant Summary: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| POS | Gene Name | Nucleotide Change | Amino acid Change | Read Depth | Percent Alt Allele | Annotation |
| 1474639 | rrl | c.982G>A | NA | 109 | 98.9 | rRNA |
| 1476311 | rrl | c.2654_2655delGTGinsCCA | NA | 100 | 11.7 | rRNA |
| 1476369 | rrl | c.2712C>T | NA | 110 | 10 | rRNA |
| 1476463 | rrl | c.2806C>T | NA | 84 | 10.7 | rRNA |
| 1476481 | rrl | c.2824T>C | NA | 100 | 13 | rRNA |
| 1476506 | rrl | c.2849T>C | NA | 92 | 12.7 | rRNA |
| 1673425 | fabG1 upstream | c.-15C>T | NA | 90 | 98.6 | Non-Coding |
| 2154724 | katG | c.1388G>T | p.Arg463Leu | 70 | 98.2 | Non-synonymous |
| 4247646 | embB | c.1133A>C | p.Glu378Ala | 110 | 98.8 | Non-synonymous |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Interpretations Summary: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Drug | Variant | Interpretation |  |  |  |  |
| INH | fabG1 upstream_c.-15C>T,katG_p.Arg463Leu | INH-R |  |  |  |  |
| RIF | No reportable variant detected | RIF-S |  |  |  |  |
| PZA | No reportable variant detected | PZA-S |  |  |  |  |
| FQ | No reportable variant detected | FQ-S |  |  |  |  |
| EMB | embB_p.Glu378Ala | EMB-S |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer using the posted tables. I have pasted your input in a notepad, saved it as csv and tuned my previous answer with it.

---

There are 2 strategies, right?

- Either open your file and run a pre-screening, documenting positions of known table delimiters, then run as many `pd.read_csv` as needed, into a list, using a comprehension,
- Or read the whole file into a dataframe and work from there to split the tables.

In both cases, the empty rows looks like usable table delimiters.

Here is the way of pandas:

---

Step 1. Read your csv file with an excess of columns. You  know your largest table's size, right?

```py
df_read = pd.read_csv(file,                      # your example, pasted back into a csv
                      sep='\t',                  # tabs for you
                      names=range(20),           # columns in excess. 
                      header=None,               # skip no line on top
                      skip_blank_lines=False     # skip no empty line -we'll use those
                     ).dropna(how='all', axis=1) # Drop excess columns
```

*Used these:*

- [Parse a CSV into a pandas dataframe without dropping empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47509402/12846804).
- [Pandas: drop columns with all NaN's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45147100/12846804)

Step 2. Use the empty **rows** as table delimiters

```py
# Flag empty rows
nullsearch = df_read.isnull().T.all() 
# Assign group index, and add it as an extra column
df_read['group'] = nullsearch.diff().ne(0).where(~nullsearch).astype(float).cumsum().fillna(0)
```

*Used these:*

- [Find element's index in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18327624/12846804)
- [How to assign unique grouping value for each sequence of consecutive True values in pandas boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66146049/12846804)

Step 3. Split the dataframe into a list containing all detected tables

```py
df_list = [df_read[df_read.group==i]
           .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
           .drop(columns='group')
           for i in df_read.group.unique() if i]
```

There are your four tables, three plus the file header, accessible as

```
df_list[0] # your file header
df_list[1]
df_list[2]
df_list[3]
```

File header:

```py
                   0                                      1
0         Sample ID:  18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54
1       Sample Name:                               18RF0375
2     Coverage Drop:                                      0
3  Pipeline Version:                                    Var
4              Date:                       01/12/2023 09:55
```

Here is for example table 2:

```py
                   0               1                        2                  3           4                   5               6
29  Variant Summary:             NaN                      NaN                NaN         NaN                 NaN             NaN
30               POS       Gene Name        Nucleotide Change  Amino acid Change  Read Depth  Percent Alt Allele      Annotation
31           1474639             rrl                 c.982G>A                NaN         109                98.9            rRNA
32           1476311             rrl  c.2654_2655delGTGinsCCA                NaN         100                11.7            rRNA
33           1476369             rrl                c.2712C>T                NaN         110                  10            rRNA
34           1476463             rrl                c.2806C>T                NaN          84                10.7            rRNA
35           1476481             rrl                c.2824T>C                NaN         100                  13            rRNA
36           1476506             rrl                c.2849T>C                NaN          92                12.7            rRNA
37           1673425  fabG1 upstream                 c.-15C>T                NaN          90                98.6      Non-Coding
38           2154724            katG                c.1388G>T        p.Arg463Leu          70                98.2  Non-synonymous
39           4247646            embB                c.1133A>C        p.Glu378Ala         110                98.8  Non-synonymous
```

Based on what looks similar in your tables except file header, some formatting could look like this:

```py
def postprocess(df):
    '''
    Format listed dataframes
    - set row 1 as column names
    - drop row 0 and 1
    - reset the index
    '''
    return df.set_axis(labels=df.iloc[1,:].values, axis=1).iloc[2:,:].reset_index(drop=True)

Variant_Summary = postprocess(df_list[2])

        POS       Gene Name        Nucleotide Change Amino acid Change Read Depth Percent Alt Allele      Annotation
0   1474639             rrl                 c.982G>A               NaN        109               98.9            rRNA
1   1476311             rrl  c.2654_2655delGTGinsCCA               NaN        100               11.7            rRNA
2   1476369             rrl                c.2712C>T               NaN        110                 10            rRNA
3   1476463             rrl                c.2806C>T               NaN         84               10.7            rRNA
4   1476481             rrl                c.2824T>C               NaN        100                 13            rRNA
5   1476506             rrl                c.2849T>C               NaN         92               12.7            rRNA
6   1673425  fabG1 upstream                 c.-15C>T               NaN         90               98.6      Non-Coding
7   2154724            katG                c.1388G>T       p.Arg463Leu         70               98.2  Non-synonymous
8   4247646            embB                c.1133A>C       p.Glu378Ala        110               98.8  Non-synonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Method for single file containing multiple dataframes**

Based on [Python Pandas - Read csv file containing multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34184841/12846804)

1. Force reading a file with an excess of columns, and the dataframe will contain all lines
2. detect table markers (with this method you have to know or expect those)
3. split tables based on these markers using groupby
4. read with columns in excess: (here 10)

```py
df_read = pd.read_csv(your_file, header=None, names=range(10))
```

2. Flag tables by recognizing their top left cells. *"your table marker ", "another table marker"* that might be names of your first column.

```py
table_names = ["table1", "table2"]
df_read['group'] = read_df[0].isin(table_names).cumsum()
```

3. Reference your tables into a dictionary:

```py
tables = {g.iloc[0,0]: g.iloc[1:] for k,g in df_read.groupby(df_read['group'])}

# Here clean-up separate tables from the generated 'tables' dictionary
```

4. Provided it makes sense to do it, you may concatenate them

```py
pd.concat(tables, axis=0)
```

You'd have to post a minimal example to get more specific advice. How does that look like on your side?

**2) Next, gather multiple files**

As in [Adding multiple text files into a Pandas dataframe ParserError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76895183/12846804)

And [Speed Up Concatenating Bin Files with Pandas and Exporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76834090/12846804)

1. Define a function dealing with a single file
2. Comprehend and concatenate the payload

```py
def file_to_df(file, force_max_columns):
    '''convert one file into one temporary dataframe'''
    # insert the above lines #

# Comprehension then concatenation
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(files_folder,"*txt")
force_max_columns = 99
df = pd.concat([file_to_df(file, force_max_columns) for file in files]

# post-processing e.g. drop void excess columns
```

Almost there. Let us know, but do post minimal example in case of difficulty. You're really going to need to show some file content.

Comment: HI sorry for the delay I had to work on something else for a while. I am back on it not but trying a different method (still trying to read in a single file with multiple tables). I just tried your code above but I am wondering where the markers should be entered for splitting the tables and also what you mean by clean up the tables from the dictionary? Also I am trying to make each table its own dataframe

Comment: And the code you provided has worked to create dictionaries but I am not sure how to get each one into a dataframe. also I have edited the post to add an example file.